# AspNetBoilerplate Core MVC Custom Login Provider

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I need to be able to authenticate/register a user from a web login using a custom provider .

Ive attempted to add a custom authentication provider using the link below.

[External Authentication](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/User-Management#external-authentication)

Ive created AlwaysTrueExternalAuthSource.cs and added it to my Core project .

```
namespace Project.Authorization.AlwaysTrue
{
    public class AlwaysTrueExternalAuthSource : DefaultExternalAuthenticationSource<Tenant, User>, ITransientDependency
    {
        public override string Name => "AlwaysTrueExternalAuthSource";

        public override Task<bool> TryAuthenticateAsync(string userNameOrEmailAddress, string plainPassword, Tenant tenant)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Then the following line in the core module PreInitialize

```
Configuration.Modules.Zero().UserManagement.ExternalAuthenticationSources.Add<AlwaysTrueExternalAuthSource>();
```

Then the documentation get a little vague. Ive noticed that the register view contains the following .

```
<input type="hidden" id="IsExternalLogin" name="IsExternalLogin" value="@Model.IsExternalLogin.ToString()" />
            <input type="hidden" id="ExternalLoginAuthSchema" name="ExternalLoginAuthSchema" value="@Model.ExternalLoginAuthSchema" />*@
```

I assumed that setting these manually would enable the new authentication source

```
  <input type="hidden" id="IsExternalLogin" name="IsExternalLogin" value="@true" />
            <input type="hidden" id="ExternalLoginAuthSchema" name="ExternalLoginAuthSchema" value="AlwaysTrueExternalAuthSource" />
```

However this failed with an error of :

```
Abp.Runtime.Validation.AbpValidationException: Method arguments are not valid! See ValidationErrors for details.
   at Abp.Runtime.Validation.Interception.MethodInvocationValidator.ThrowValidationError() in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Runtime\Validation\Interception\MethodInvocationValidator.cs:line 118
```

Could anyone help explain where i'm going wrong here please.

I should explain that the provider has given me a set of API's that i can query via a post request. So the ultimate goal is to override the register and login methods in order to authenticate via this 3rd party service.